# My spring batch reader is not picking up files with no extension for processing, its ignoring them

Tags: spring-batch

I am using FlatFileItemReader in spring batch framework. Some of my files are .txt (testfile1.txt) files but strangely some files do not have any extension (testfile2). My spring batch reader is not picking up files with no extension for processing, its ignoring them. Is there a way my flatfile Item reader reads files with no extention?

I am using multi resource item reader as follows

```
@Bean
    @StepScope
    @Qualifier("monthlyReconciliationMultiResourceItemReader")
    public MultiResourceItemReader monthlyReconciliationMultiResourceItemReader() {
      FileSystemResourceLoader fileSystemResourceLoader=new FileSystemResourceLoader();
        ResourcePatternResolver patternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(fileSystemResourceLoader);
        Resource[] resources = null;
        try {

            resources = patternResolver.getResources(FilePathModifier.resolveTenantFilePath(tenantRequestContext.getCurrentTenant(), (getMonthlyReconFilePath())));
            MultiResourceItemReader<Object> multiResourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
            multiResourceItemReader.setResources(resources);
            multiResourceItemReader.setDelegate(monthlyReconciliationFlatFileItemReader());
            return multiResourceItemReader;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: please share your code. I think you have wrong configuration for `FlatFIleItemReader` bean

Answer (score 1):

try and find out what this line does -

```
  resources = patternResolver.getResources(FilePathModifier.resolveTenantFilePath(tenantRequestContext.getCurrentTenant(), (getMonthlyReconFilePath())));
```

see here -->

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/ResourcePatternResolver.html

It says -->

```
Resource[]  getResources(String locationPattern)
Resolve the given location pattern into Resource objects.
```

You need to give pattern here -->

```
patternResolver.getResources(filePath with pattern);
```

Comment: have added my code block, I am using multi resource item reader as mentioned. how to add pattern in this case?

Comment: this helped. Thanks. Location pattern was set to folder/*.* which is why it was ignoring files without extension.

Comment: great, so now you can read any files with given regular expression

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way my flatfile Item reader reads files with no extention?

All Spring Batch file readers work with the `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` interface from Spring Framework. They are not concerned whether a file has an extension or not.

Before configuring the `MultiResourceItemReader` and its delegate `FlatFileItemReader`, you need to unit test the code that resolves the `Resource[]` array and make sure it resolves files with no extension.

Comment: Yeah, Resource[] array was coming empty.